# Getting value out of selected td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp, jquery-ui-selectable

Currently i have a selectable table which i can drag and select tds in a column. However i would like to get all the values from each of this td cells. How do i go about doing this? i have tried .each() but it still does not work

```
<style type="text/css">
.ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
.ui-selected { background: #F39814; }
</style>

<script>
    $(function() {
    $("table").selectable({
        filter: ".tdItem"
    });
});
</script>
</head>     

<body>


<table width="100%" border="1">
<%
    for(String t: time){
        out.println("<tr>");
        int i=0;
        for(String room: rooms){
            out.println("<td class='tdItem' align='center'>");
            out.println(room+" "+t);
            out.println("</td>");
            i++;
        }
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
%>
```

Comment: get the values where/when? `$('td.tdItem')`?

Comment: how should i even iterate through the tds which i selected?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all the td's in your document and check if has the selected class..

IF yes then get that
Try this

```
var $td = $('tr td');

$.each($td , function(i){
     if( $(this).hasClass('tdItem'){
        console.log($(this).text())
     }
});
​
```

Comment: but all my tds have the same class. This would give me all the tds information and not the selected 1s

Comment: But if your td's are selected then it will be given a different class right.. Find out what that class is by inspecting the element

Comment: Why not just `$('td.tdItem')`? no point in looping over all tds yourself when jquery can do the filtering for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use element.innerText to get the text content of any HTML element. For example, on this page you can use `$(".question-hyperlink")[0].innerText` to get the question text. $(selector)[0] is a plain old HTML element.

Or, staying in jQuery, you can use `$(selector).text()` to do the same thing. Something like `$(".question-hyperlink").text()` works exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0):

get TD of each TR

```
$('table tr').each( function(i){
     $('td',this).each(function(){
           console.log($(this).text())
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The selectable plugin adds the class `ui-selected` to any selected element, so simply:

```
$('.ui-selected')
```

will give you all selected elements. Limit to your `.tdItem`s if you have other selectable things by using:

```
$('.tdItem.ui-selected')
```

If you want to do something every time the selection changes, then you can use [the `selected` or `stop` callback in the `.selectable({...})` options](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/). Putting it all together gives us something like:

```
function afterSelectionChanged(event, ui){    
    var $selectedElements = $('.tdItem.ui-selected');
    // Do something with the selected elements
}

$("table").selectable({
    filter:'.tdItem',
    stop: afterSelectionChanged 
});
```

[See jsfiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/nXKWF/9/).